# Prisma DB connection times out when inserting data through sub-queries

Tags: prisma

I'm using Prisma 5.8.0 with a postgres DB.

I have the following models/tables, with `Model1` in a one-to-many relation with `Model2` and `Model3`:

```
model Model1 {
  id      Int      @id
  model2s Model2[]
  model3s Model3[]
}

model Model2 {
  id       Int    @id @unique @default(autoincrement())
  Model1   Model1 @relation(fields: [model1Id], references: [id])
  model1Id Int
}

model Model3 {
  id       Int    @id @unique @default(autoincrement())
  Model1   Model1 @relation(fields: [model1Id], references: [id])
  model1Id Int
}
```

I tried to insert the data for Model1 and all related Model2 and Model3 instances:

```
prismadb.model1.create({
  data: {
    ...data1,
    model2: { 
      create: data2.map(({ field2 }) => ({ data: field2 })), 
    },
    model3: { 
      create: data3.map(({ field3 }) => ({ data: field3 })), 
    },
  },
})
```

But I got the following timeout error:

```
 ⨯ PrismaClientKnownRequestError: 
Invalid `prisma.model1.create()` invocation:

Timed out fetching a new connection from the connection pool. More info: http://pris.ly/d/connection-pool (Current connection pool timeout: 10, connection limit: 21)
```

However, the below code does not produce a connection timeout.

```
prismadb.$transaction([
  prismadb.model1.create({
    data: data1,
  }),
  // model2 and model3 are in a many-to-one relationship with model1
  prismadb.model2.createMany({
    data: data2.map(({ field2 }) => ({ id: data1.id, data: field2 })),
  }),
  prismadb.model3.createMany({
    data: data3.map(({ field3 }) => ({ id: data1.id, data: field3 })),
  }),
]);
```

Why does only the first way result in an error?